# Need help finding n amount of Excel Ranges

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

So I have this situation:

At work I need to make an Excel AddIn which can collect some data from user surveys and show them in a neat little Excel Report. I have the format down however I have trouble figuring out how I find the Excel Ranges needed to showcase the questions that were asked in the survey.

Every question needs to take up three cells each since there are three stats associated with each and that's fine until you reach Z and have to start over with AA, AB, AC, etc. I can't quite wrap my head around it and I feel my current solution is being needlessly complicated. I know that right now there are 13 questions. That's 39 cells I need for the questions total but that could change in the future, or I might have to find smaller reports than all of the 13 questions. I need to make sure my algorithm can take care of both scenarios.

Currently I have this:

```
const String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int alphabetCounter = 0;
int alphabetIndex = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < dict["questions"].Length; i++)
{
    String start = "";
    String end = "";

    if ((alphabetIndex + 1) > ALPHABET.Length)
    {
        alphabetCounter++;
        alphabetIndex = 0;
        start += ALPHABET[alphabetCounter - 1] + ALPHABET[alphabetIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        start += ALPHABET[alphabetIndex];
        alphabetIndex++;
    }


    if ((alphabetIndex + 1) > ALPHABET.Length)
    {
        alphabetCounter++;
        alphabetIndex = 0;
        end += ALPHABET[alphabetIndex];
    }
    else
    {
        alphabetIndex++;
        end += ALPHABET[alphabetIndex];
    }

    Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range(start + "7", end + "7");
    questionRanges.Add(range);
}
```

It's not finished because I ran into a wall here. So just to explain:

- `ALPHABET` is just that. The alphabet. I use that to get the cell letters.
- `AlphabetCounter` is how many times I have gone through the alphabet so in the event that I need to add an extra letter in front of my cells letter (Like the A in AB) I can get that from the `ALPHABET` string
- `AlphabetIndex` is where in the alphabet I currently am.

I hope you can help me.

How would I go about getting all the ranges I need to accompany the n amount of questions I can get details about?

Comment: Why dont you use UsedRange property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange.aspx

Comment: @Abbas I'm sorry but how does it help me when I need to get a set of ranges in a single row and then fill them with data after? I don't really care about what cells have already been used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial solution would be to change

```
const string ALPHABET = "ABC..."
```

to

```
const string[] ColumnNames = { "A", "B", "C", ..., "Z", "AA".. }
```

But this doesn't scale well. Think about what happens when you need to add a column. You'd have to add another item in the array, and eventually you'd have 26^2 array entries. Certainly not ideal.

A better solution would be to treat the column index as a base 26 number and convert it using a function like the following:

```
string GetColumnName(int index)
{
    List<char> chars = new List<char>();
    while (index >= 0)
    {
        int current = index % 26;
        chars.Add((char)('A' + current));
        index = (int)((index - current) / 26) - 1;
    }
    chars.Reverse();
    return new string(chars.ToArray());
}
```

The function here converts the base by repeatedly calculating the remainder (also known as modulus or `%`).

Comment: So, how would this work? Would I call this method to gain a single cell? If so, what does Index represent? The index of the question array?

Comment: @Vipar The index of the column. ie "A" = 0, "B"=1, "AA" = 26, "AB" = 27, etc

Answer (score 1):

just another idea of implementation, maybe it can be useful:

```
    ...
    List<char> start = new List<char>();
    List<char> end = new List<char>();

    start = Increment(end);
    Increment(end);
    Increment(end);

    Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range(new String(start.ToArray())+ "7", 
                                        new String(end.ToArray())+ "7");
}

private List<char> Increment(List<char> listColumn, int position=0)
{
    if (listColumn.Count > position)
    {
        listColumn[position]++;
        if (listColumn[position] == '[')
        {
            listColumn[position] = 'A';
            Increment(listColumn, ++position);
        }
    }
    else
    {
            listColumn.Add('A');
    }

    return listColumn;
}
```